# "Follow protocol" or "follow the protocol"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Could you tell me if I have use *the* before *protocol* on the context below.

> Sorry, sir, but I can't give you any information on that account without verifying your information first. I understand your frustration because it takes time, but I'm just **following** (**the**) **protocol**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if the speaker is referring to a written document specifying a fixed set of rules, *the protocol* might be alright.

I think it also works without *the* if the speaker is referring generally to his understanding of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are [in common use...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow%20protocol%2Cfollow%20the%20protocol%2Cfollowed%20protocol%2Cfollowed%20the%20protocol&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image]

It's normally entirely a stylistic choice whether to include the article or not. If a *specific* "protocol" has been previously mentioned, I'd say the article is more likely to be included (but it's only *more likely* - it's never *required*).

But if you want a "general principle" for making the choice here, my advice would be *not* to include the article unless it's contextually *necessary* to indicate that you're only referring to some specific contextually-identified protocol, rather than just "diplomatic conventions" in general.